# ggplot2 color for x and y by value

Tags: r, ggplot2

been looking for hours,i tried all solution with breaks, cut...
here is my problem :
i have a data frame like this :

```
           col1          col2
1          NA            NA
2          NA          4.73
3          NA            NA
4          NA            NA
5          NA            NA
6        8.72          7.64
7        2.32            NA
8          NA            NA
9        8.29          6.23
10       9.36          7.72
```

and i plot it like this:

```
scatter_plot <- ggplot(AB2, aes(col1,col2))

scatter_plot + geom_point(color=ifelse(col1>5,"#5DCA03","red")) +
  labs(x = "col2", y = "col1") + geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

but i what i want exactly is that point are red when col1 OR col2 < 5
here i only get red point for col1 < 5

thanks you

**edit:**

after applying **Luke Hayden** solution:

```
scatter_plot <- ggplot(AB2, aes(col1,col2))

scatter_plot + geom_point(color=ifelse(col1<5 | col2<5,"red","#5DCA03")) +
  labs(x = "col2", y = "col1") + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

i get this plot [rplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E9dm.png)

though i don't understand why i have red points with value > 5 for col1 and col2

**2nd edit:**

after the last edit from **Luke Hayden** i fixed the problem, though i had to set the lm color to blue, otherwise i had 2 lm : 1 for point value < 5 and 1 for point value > 5. Now the code looks like that:

```
scatter_plot <- ggplot(AB2, aes(col1,col2, col=valid))

scatter_plot + geom_point() +
  labs(x = "col2", y = "col1") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","#5DCA03"))+
  geom_smooth(method="lm", color="blue")
```

Comment: First, you need to put color definition with `aes`. Second, `col1 > 5` what you need  (remove `ifelse`) as you will be passing logical vector. Finally, specify wanted colors using function: `scale_color_manual` (argument `values`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to add an extra column checking if a column has an entry >5. Like so:

```
AB <- data.frame(a= c(0, 3, 1, 6), b= c(2,7, NA, 2))
AB$isred <- apply(AB, 1, max, na.rm=T) >5

ggplot(data= AB, aes(x=a, y=b, col=isred))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black","red"))
```

You could also simply change your `ifelse` to require either condition to be true:

```
color=ifelse(col1>5 | col2>5,"#5DCA03","red")
```

After discussing below, I understand this as you looking for both to be > 5. 
In that case, use:

```
AB <- data.frame(a= c(0, 3, 1, 6), b= c(2,7, NA, 8))
AB$isred <- AB$a > 5 & AB$b >5


ggplot(data= AB, aes(x=a, y=b, col=isred))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black","red"))
```

Or simply:

```
color=ifelse(col1>5 & col2>5,"#5DCA03","red")
```

Comment: ok thanks you ! i tried this but no with the right syntax...
but now i have an other problems, looks like my point doesn't the axis
i have red point with both value > 5
i don't understand...

Comment: Could you be clearer? I don't understand what the issue is

Comment: Did you try it using my first method? Could you provide your data with dput(AB2)?

Comment: yes, fact is that with your first method it only works for the first col: if col 1 > 5, set True even if col2 <5 
But what i want is to set True only in col1 AND col2 >5, or to set False if col1 OR col2 < 5

Comment: I thought that you wanted it red if either were >5, but you want it red only if both are > 5, right?

Comment: yes, my condition is TRUE if col1 > 5 AND col2 > 5, in any other case it's FALSE

Comment: ok thanks, it works ! it was my first idea to do it this way, though i hoped something like your 2 method, but looks like it's not working the way i wanted which is weird...
nb : i had to set the lm color to blue, otherwise i had 2 lm : 1 for point < 5 and 1 for point > 5